# Avoid automatic transition of QGraphicsScene on QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, qt

Qt's `QGraphicsView` has a habit of automatic transition/sliding of the view in such a way that everything drawn on the attached `QGraphicsScene` is visible. For example, suppose you've drawn something on the scene and viewing in the view. Now upon a button press you draw something along the right edge of the view. The scene/view will slide to the right slightly so that everything is again visible.

I want to prevent this to happen. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scene rectangle of QGraphicsScene is by default the bounding rectangle of all the items in the scene. As such it grows when items are added.
The scene rectangle of QGraphicsView is by default taken from QGraphicsScene::sceneRect. If you don't want this to change automatically you can set one explicitly with QGraphicsView::setSceneRect.